# why no warning for implicit type conversion?

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion

I finally figured out a bug in my program, which caused by the implicit type conversion on return type. Even with `g++ -Wall` there is no warning for this.

I wonder if there is someway to quickly find out such mindless errors?

```
#include <iostream>

// return type should be int, but I wrote bool by mistake
bool foo(int x) {
  return x;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::cout << foo(i) << std::endl;
    // 0 1 1 1 1 1  ..
    // should be 0 1 2 3 4 ...
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because compiler warnings are very poorly implemented. That's why third-party static analysis tools exist.

Comment: A `bool` is either `true` (`1`) or false (`0`). In C++ all non-zero values are considered to be `true`, so returning any non-zero value from your function will be converted to `true` (i.e. `1`). You can never expect a `bool` to be anything else (like `2` or `3`) like you want.

Comment: To add more warnings, try the flags `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`.

Comment: Are you asking for warnings in every implicit type conversion?  Whoa nelly....

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I tried http://gcc.godbolt.org/ - no warning with those keys.

Comment: I am surprised by the comment `"should be 0 1 2 3 4..."`. You might expect a warning, but you certainly cannot expect `0 1 2 3 4`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the most relevant warning is `-Wconversion`, and that is not activated with `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, but it doesn't trigger a warning for int to bool conversion (which I think is actually fine).

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, the bug is I set the foo's return type to `bool` accidentlly, which should be `int`

Comment: So a good case why unit-testing is useful, even in small projects. :)

Comment: The real WTF is the "not even with -Wall" statement by the OP, or that the option is called "all" when it is merely all the warnings that are *undisputed*. Too many people are fooled into believing that "-Wall" turns on "all" warnings, when not even "-Wextra" does that...

Answer (score 3):

This is correct code. if (i) where `i` has type `int` is correct too.

n3376 4.12/1

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
> any other value is converted to true.

Comment: +1 for citing the standard, but (strictly speaking) it is not an answer. Warnings are usually issued when _correct_ code may hide potential semantic errors. It is exactly the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal type promotion.
From the C++ standard:

> `bool`, `char`, `wchar_t`, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively 
>       called integral types

and:

> An rvalue of type `bool` can be converted to an rvalue of type
>       `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

Comment: The conversion is actually `int` to `bool` in this example.

Comment: @juanchopanza: There are actually two conversions. Regarding the part you are refererring, ForEveE has already cited the standard.

Comment: OK, I am failing to see one of those conversions.

Comment: The second is the promotion it mentioned (since there is no explicit <<(bool) ). But you are right, ForEveR's case is the more interesting.

Comment: The `basic_ostream::operator<<` member function has an overload for `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Iddeed, most(all?) compilers seem conceptually inconsistent when they usually warn about possible losing of significant digits or precision (for instance in case of int to char conversion or similar) but make an exception for conversion to bool.

I suppose there are only historical reasons for that.

A lot of legacy code uses constructs like

if(number)... or if(pointer) ...

instead of

if(number!=0)... or if(pointer!=NULL) ...

Moreover, the latter style often regarded as too verbose.

The tradition is convinient, allows to write concise code,  but it is indeed error prone. It is not supported (consciously) in some another languages (e.g.Java).

Comment: Yes, Java has many beginner-friendly features that get in the way when you are no longer a beginner.

Comment: @Pete:  I'm not biased in my answer (in favor of java :), I just explain the difference. And I generally agree that many Java features are burdensome, but this particular case is a simple oversight (not a typical "beginner error") and results in runtime error instead of complile time error (or at least warning).