# 'Int' is not convertible to type 'double'

Tags: c++, int, double, visual-c++

I keep getting this error at run-time: "'Int' is not convertible to type 'double'", it displays this as soon as I run the program, but then it quickly disappears and then shows my program. I'm using VC2010. (EDIT: This program is to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, and to tell if it's hot or not hot.)

```
#include <iostream>

int convert(int);

int main(void)
{
     using std::cout;
     using std::cin;
     using std::endl;

     cout << "Enter the degrees in Celsius: ";

     int temp;
     cin >> temp;
     int degrees = convert(temp);

if(degrees<100)
{
    cout << degrees << " is not too hot." << endl;
}

else if(degrees>100)
{
    cout << degrees << " is hot." << endl;
}

      cin.get();
      cin.get();
      return 0;
    }


int convert(int ctf)
{
     return ctf * 1.8 + 32;
}
```

Comment: The only logic error I see is that your program prints no message if the temperature in degrees is precisely 100.  Mixing `int` and `double` like this isn't great form (the expression `ctf * 1.8` combines an `int` and a `double`), but I don't see why it should give you a runtime error with this program.

Comment: Thanks, I am still unsure as to why it does too.  But I also did not notice that I have used a double with an int in my expression ( i was just typing away). This may be the cause of the error; however, would'nt it just convert it to an Int type with a little loss of data?

Comment: Yeah, it should just convert.  I can see getting a compiler _warning_ maybe, but not a runtime _error_ with reasonable values for the celsius temperature.  If you really want to do this with integer arithmetic, write `ctf * 9 / 5 + 32`.

Comment: An aside... resist using ctf and such as variable names.  ctf means nothing when reading the function signature.  int convert_cel_to_fer(int celsius) would be a way better signature.  I only say because this is obvious homework and I'd personally doc marks for bad names.

Comment: Thank you for your help and staying active here. That is a great idea. I am still getting a runtime error and not a warning though; however my code does work with devC++ and code::blocks. Maybe a VC2010 error?

Comment: can you post the exact error message?

Comment: @baash05 thank you. I just used 'ctf' to stand for 'Celsius to Fahrenheit'. Hopefully I would not get marked for it. I will change it though.

Comment: My problem has been solved. For some reason explicitly casting the result of my convert function, the error went away. Weird. I was just expecting something like a warning, but not runtime error. It also seems like I can't get the error to come back as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly cast the result of `convert` method to int to avoid this message.

```
int convert(int ctf)
{
     return (int) (ctf * 1.8 + 32);
}
```

Since the return type is specified ad `int`, but the result of the float multiplication is not `int`, it is showing this message.
However, since you are converting temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit, it is better to use `double` or `float` values instead of `int` to yield more accurate and meaningful output.

Comment: But why is it a _runtime_ _error_?  It should be at most a compile-time _warning_.  Also, why did it complain about converting `int` to `double`, rather than the other way around?

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135196/why-no-warning-for-implicit-type-conversion

Comment: I'm sorry, how does that help? I'm curious about why it's a error too.

Comment: It will be a compile-time error only for languages which have `Type safety` (e.g. Java), since C++ doesnot impose `type safety`, many consider it as a weakly typed language. The runtime message which is displayed is compiler specific - so when the compiler detects an unsafe conversion, it issues either an error or a warning depending on vendor implementation

Comment: The conversion is valid and well-defined. The cast **only** silences a compiler warning that tells you that you might not be smart enough to use this feature correctly. Any runtime message means that the compiler is totally non-conforming.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a compiler warning informing you of a loss of precision by specifying that `convert` returns an `int` while the expression `ctf * 1.8 + 32` returns a `double` as `1.8` is of type `double`. Arithmetic expressions involving variables of type `int` and `double` will promote the resulting type to `double`. I recommend updating your `convert` function to:

```
double convert(double ctf)
```

If you insist on using integers, make the appropriate cast:

```
int convert(int ctf)
{
     return static_cast<int>(ctf * 1.8 + 32);
}
```

Comment: Why is the warning in the other direction then, saying an `int` can't be converted to a `double`?

Comment: This is a great answer, but when I change the convert function as said, and the prototype function to 'double convert(double)', I still manage to get the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the convert function, by multiplying a int with a decimal you are automatically converting it to a double. so either return a double, or cast it to a int

Comment: just to add, a int is convertible to a double because it looses no precision(e.g. 1 == 1.0) but when you convert it the other way, double to int. it looses precision and you get runtime errors

Comment: It shouldn't be a runtime error.  It should just truncate.  It could trap if it's out of range for an int, but it shouldn't be in this code.

Comment: you are right, however I do remember encountering this error years back when I was learning c++ in high school. In any case, i wrote a small test program and it gave no errors

Comment: **NO**, this is **not** a runtime error. The conversion is well-defined and meaningful. Adding a cast **only** tells the compiler not to warn you that you might not be smart enough to use this feature correctly.